# List of running applications missing from Task Manager in XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, task-manager

I'm enclosing a screenshot if it lets me, but here goes.

When I press CTRL-ALT-DEL for Task Manager it comes up but the first pane, which usually lists everything I have running (like Firefox Browser for instance) comes up blank.  I can still see all that's running via the Processes tab but I've kinda gotten used to highlighting the offending task in the first pane, right-clicking and choosing 'Go To Process' (if I've got the wording slightly wrong from memory, forgive me) to find the main process so I can kill it cleanly.  Especially if it's a hung browser, doing that will find the main browser so I don't have to kill it tab by tab.

[image]

I know there might be other ways of doing a clean kill if necessary, that's not the question.  The question IS - why isn't the list showing up in the first pane any more? If it helps, and it well might, I was in Services.MSC the other day and there's a very slight chance (OK, with me not so slight!) I might've turned off something by mistake that's doing it. Again I might NOT have done, so don't get hooked on that idea, but IF I have, what would it have been?

I'm happy to try other things too, short of reinstalling XP, though I can do that as a last resort.

Any ideas?

Yours puzzledly

Chris.

Comment: So which service did you disable exactly?  Without know which service you disable, your question will be nearly impossible to answer, so please provide that information

Comment: Fix here.....https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/windows-xp-task-manager-not-showing-apps-running.1001677/